# Python: argparse optional arguments without dashes

Tags: python, argparse, optional-arguments

I would like to have the following syntax:

```
python utility.py file1 FILE1 file2 FILE2
```

where file1 and file2 are optional arguments.
It is simple to make it working with this syntax:

```
python utility.py --file1 FILE1 --file2 FILE2
```

using

```
parser.add_argument('--file1',type=file)
parser.add_argument('--file2',type=file)
```

however, if I remove the dashes, argparse starts to interprete it as a positional rather than optional argument...

In other words, is it possible to specifically tell argparse whether an argument is optional or positional so that I can have optional parameters without the dashes?

Comment: That syntax (no dashes) is confusing as hell! There is a reason the convention exists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it may be confusing but for some scientific applications this is a standard... [example](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/html/refmac5/description.html)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: counterexample: the `git` or `svn` command line interface.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: those are subcommands, not switches. Each subcommand takes options, which use dashes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that is just semantics, no difference from the syntax point of view - arguments with no dashes. Not (directly) supported by argparse for whatever semantics. BTW, they are not switches in my example either (but that is irrelevant as I have just mentioned).

Comment: @jvm: subcommands do not usually share switches. There is a shared level (`git --version`) and per-subcommand switches (`git checkout --patch`). Don't just dismiss the semantics here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to get `argparse` to do this for you.  However, you can make `argparse` accept any number of positional arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('FILES',nargs='*')
options=parser.parse_args()
file1,optional_files=options.FILES[0],options.FILES[1:]
```

Of course, you may want to add some checks to make sure that at least 1 file was given, etc.

**EDIT**

I'm still not 100% sure what you want here, but if `file1` and `file2` are literal strings, you can work around that a little bit by preprocessing `sys.argv`.  Of course, this will still format your help message strangely, but you can always add an epilog explaining that either form is OK:

```
import argparse
import sys

mangle_args=('file1','file2')
arguments=['--'+arg if arg in mangle_args else arg for arg in sys.argv[1:]]

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--file1')
parser.add_argument('--file2')
options=parser.parse_args(arguments)
```

Comment: Positional arguments are not sufficient for me. For example, file1 may be skipped, file2 inputted, file3 skipped, file4 inputted and the  assignment is important (ie I need to know that it was file2 and file4 that were specified by the user)

Comment: @jvm -- How is argparse (or anything) supposed to know that the file you gave is `file2` instead of `file1`?  If you can't sort it out from the order it came on the commandline, certainly `argparse` can't do it either.

Comment: Are `file1` and `file2` constant strings, or are they names of files -- maybe that's what I'm not understanding here...

Comment: @jvm -- I think I now understand what you're trying to do.  I've posted a "workaround".  It's a little ugly, but it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this is a working solution indeed. I was hoping I was missing some argparse function that would allow me this directly but if that is not possible then your workaround is probably the best. Just some nitpicking - of course you also need to import argparse in your example.

Comment: @jvm -- I left it off because you did in your original example.  Anyway, it's in there now.

Comment: @mgilson, it's a good workaround but `--help` still contains those dashes.

Answer (score 3):

Another Example would be:

`train.py`

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Arguments for wake_word")
    parser.add_argument('data', type=str, help="path to data")
    parser.add_argument('output', type=str, help="model save path")
    parser.add_argument('batch_size', type=int, help="batch size")
    parser.add_argument('epochs', type=int, help="no.s of epochs")
    args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.data + args.output + args.batch_size + args.epochs)
```

then you can just run this code with arguments without dash

```
train.py /path/to/data/ /path/to/output_files/ 128 100
```

And, in ascending order

Comment: the question is talking about optional arguments without dashes, not positional arguments

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. My workaround is:

```
lastarg = sys.argv[-1]
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and lastarg[0] != '-':
    sys.argv[-1] = '-file'
    sys.argv.append(lastarg)

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('-d', action='store_true')
argparser.add_argument('-nrv', action='store_true')
argparser.add_argument('-file', type=str, default='')
args = argparser.parse_args()
```